# Difference between NSAffinetransform and CGAffinetransform

Tags: iphone, cgaffinetransform

Does anyone have any good example which explain difference between `NSAffinetransform` and `CGAffinetransform`??
Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Simple answer: `NSAffinetransform` its for the Mac osx `CGAffinetransform` is for the iOS
However there are differences between these classes

Comment: CGAffineTransform is present and used on Mac OS X too.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan yes you are right, i probably should update the answer

Answer (score -2):

One difference is that NSAffineTransform is an object, while CGAffineTransform is a struct.